# dispatch action ngrx not working with effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, effects

I'm new with the use of ngrx on angular, when I dispatch to the Authentication action nothing happens I don't even have errors in the console can someone tell me where the error is!
I think the problem in the dispatch or effects does not detect the action!

```
     //action.ts
        export const cuurentUser=createAction('currentUser',props<any>());
        export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
        export const Authentication = createAction(
            LOGIN, 
            props<{payload: any}>()
          );
       ///components.ts
        login(){
          
        this.store.dispatch(Authentication(this.params))
          }

  

        ///effects.ts
       @Injectable()
    export class AuthenticationEffects{
    
        
       
        user=createEffect(()=>this.action.pipe(
            ofType(LOGIN),
            map((action:typeof Authentication)=>action),
            tap((payload:any)=>{
             
               this.authService.login(payload).pipe(
                map((resp)=>{
                    cuurentUser(payload.username)
                 console.log(resp)
                 
                 
                
                }),
                catchError(error=>of(console.log(error)) )
              )
            })
        )
        )  

 ///module.ts
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AuthenticationRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({reducerA:AuthenticationReducer}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthenticationEffects])
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You done a silly mistake which is `ofType(LOGIN)` instead of use `ofType(Authentication)`.

`LOGIN` is just a string not an action.
for more you can see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ep8tz6)

click on button `Store Check`.

Comment: share  stackblitz code so i can help you.